# consulta de Sql Server que me arroje un registro por valor distinto solo en la primera columna

Tags: sql

gracias por escucharme, tengo una consulta de Sql con 4 columnas, de las cuales necesito que me traiga el primer valor de cada registro de la columna NIS, y no repita el resto.

```
select
    TEST.Nis,
    PNOW.idService,
    PNOW.name,
    PNOW.address,
    (7918 * acos(  cos( radians(pall.lat))/*vieja LAT*/--3959
                  * cos( radians(PNOW.lat) )
                  * cos( radians(PNOW.lng) - radians(PALL.lng/*vieja lng*/) )--punto viejo 256
                  + sin( radians(PALL.lat/*vieja LAT*/) ) * sin( radians(pnow.lat))
                 )) AS distance,
    Error_web
FROM
    orderstest TEST
    inner join P380PuntosP PALL--todos puntos
    on Nis=Pall.idService--NIS233
    and error_web='Error'
    Left join P380PPickit PNOW --puntos ahora
    on PNOW.idservice!=pall.idservice
group by PNOW.idService,
    PNOW.name,
    PNOW.address,
    error_web,
    Nis,
    (7918 * acos(  cos( radians(pall.lat))/*vieja LAT*/--3959
                  * cos( radians(PNOW.lat) )
                  * cos( radians(PNOW.lng) - radians(PALL.lng/*vieja lng*/) )--punto viejo 
                  + sin( radians(PALL.lat/*vieja LAT*/) ) * sin( radians(pnow.lat))
                 ))
    ORDER BY  distance asc
```

me trae esto:[image: l]

Lo que necesito es que me arroje solo el primer registro de 2771 y el primer registro de 2731, en la consulta ya esta ordenado por cercania, es para ubicar los locales mas cercanos al local(NIS) que ya no esta habilitado.

Answer (score 1):

lo resolvi haciendo la consulta en subconsulta en From y agregando el campo rownumber. quedo asi la Query

```
    select * From 
    (select 
        TEST.Nis,
        PNOW.idService,
        PNOW.name,
        PNOW.address,
        /*PNOW.lat,
        PNOW.lng,
        PALL.lat,
        PALL.lng,*/
        (7918 * acos(  cos( radians(pall.lat))/*vieja LAT*/--3959
                      * cos( radians(PNOW.lat) )
                      * cos( radians(PNOW.lng) - radians(PALL.lng/*vieja lng*/) )--punto viejo 256
                      + sin( radians(PALL.lat/*vieja LAT*/) ) * sin( radians(pnow.lat))
                     )) AS [distance],
        Error_web,
    

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TEST.Nis ORDER BY (7918 * acos(  cos( radians(pall.lat))/*vieja LAT*/--3959
                      * cos( radians(PNOW.lat) )
                      * cos( radians(PNOW.lng) - radians(PALL.lng/*vieja lng*/) )--punto viejo 256
                      + sin( radians(PALL.lat/*vieja LAT*/) ) * sin( radians(pnow.lat))
                     )) asc) AS [ROW NUMBER]

    FROM
        orderstest TEST
        inner join P380PuntosP PALL--todos puntos
        on Nis=Pall.idService--NIS233
        and error_web='Error'
        Left join P380PPickit PNOW --puntos ahora
        on PNOW.idservice!=pall.idservice
    group by PNOW.idService,
        PNOW.name,
        PNOW.address,
        error_web,
        Nis,
        (7918 * acos(  cos( radians(pall.lat))/*vieja LAT*/--3959
                      * cos( radians(PNOW.lat) )
                      * cos( radians(PNOW.lng) - radians(PALL.lng/*vieja lng*/) )--punto viejo 256
                      + sin( radians(PALL.lat/*vieja LAT*/) ) * sin( radians(pnow.lat))
                     ))
        )DATA
    WHERE DATA.[ROW NUMBER] = 1
```

Desde ya muchas gracias, espero le sirva a alguien mas.